# When to use setUserAuthenticationRequired

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore

I am a little confused as to when should I use the `android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder setUserAuthenticationRequired` method. I understand that the main purpose of using this method is to bind to the lockscreen credential as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder#setEncryptionRequired()). But I can't understand what is the added security benefit of creating this binding.
Relevant links:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UserAuthentication

I am especially not able to understand this line in the above link

> This is an advanced security feature that is generally useful only if your requirements are that a compromise of your application process after key generation/import (but not before or during) can't bypass the requirement for the user to be authenticated to use the key.

Thanks in advance.